# ODBC login is trying to use Windows authentication even though I supply SQL Server credentials

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, odbc, jdbc-odbc

I am having trouble connecting to my Microsoft Server 2008 using the JdbcOdbc driver in Java. I prefer to use the Jdbc driver over the windows driver as the client has multiple options to connect with. The connection string I am using is:

```
jdbc:odbc:Driver={SQL Server};SERVER=hostname;database=CadSysDB;user=sqlusername;pass=sqlpassword;}
```

The server does not make use of Windows Authentication, but SQL Authentication.

The error I am receiving is:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.
```

I believe it could be a problem in my connection string, any advice?

Comment: Try `Uid=sqlusername;Pwd=sqlpassword;Trusted_Connection=no;`.

Comment: Please can you post that as an answer, as I would like to mark it as a answer. Thanks!

Comment: there seem to be one extra curly brace in your first code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Driver={SQL Server}` ODBC driver does not recognize `user=` as a connection string parameter name so it tries to log into the SQL Server without passing any SQL Server credentials (i.e., using Windows Authentication).

Passing the SQL Server credentials using the `Uid=` and `Pwd=` parameters

```
Uid=sqlusername;Pwd=sqlpassword
```

will get the `{SQL Server}` ODBC to try and log in using SQL Authentication. We can also explicitly pass a parameter for `Trusted_Connection=no`, but that is not really required if `Uid` and `Pwd` are provided.